# Import SAS file to SQL Server using Bulk Insert

Tags: ssis, insert, sas, bulk

I have 25 million records that needs to be imported to SQL Server every week.   I have an SSIS package that currently load the data but it takes almost 10 hrs to load.  I would like to use Bulk Insert but it does not have the option to use SAS files.

I appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks,
ramamosn

Comment: How are you currently loading to SQL Server?  Are you using the SAS OLEDB driver, or CozyRoc, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is likely in the commit interval.
by default it performs every 1000 - 10,000 depending on the database.
In your `libname` set `dbcommit=` to a higher value. I would start at 100,000. If you use `dbcommit=0` it will perform only one commit.
The other option to set is `bulkload=yes`

your code would look something like this:

```
libname sqlsrv user=scott password=tiger ... bulkload=yes dbcommit=100000;
   data sqlsrv.mydata;
      set mydata;
   run;
```

Here is a link to the documentation: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/69039/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00lgy3xwh61b8n16kffwq3veagu.htm